# Why is Surface Pro pen sending WM_HSCROLL and WM_VSCROLL when the pen is down?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, tablet

I'm building a drawing application for Windows desktop (Visual Studio 2019, C++, MFC). I'm using `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` to plot pixels when the user is moving the mouse with the left button down.

When I test it on a Surface Pro 4, if I press the pen down on the screen and move - expecting it to draw - the client window scrolls instead. Spy++ shows a lot of `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL` messages going to the window, and the occasional `WM_POINTERUPDATE` message.

Is there a Win32 API I should be calling to change this behaviour? Or does anyone have any insight into what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Does calling [`RegisterTouchWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) inhibit the generation of (compatibility) mouse messages?

Comment: @inspectable I didn't have that in my code. I've added it now, as soon as I touch the display with the pen it throws a debug asset for mfc140ud.dll wincore.cpp line 1665. Clicking ignore repeats the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable I've got it working!! Thank you very much, that sorted it out. The debug asset is thrown if the application window doesn't have a message handler for WM_TOUCH (I found this out through trial and error). Please post your suggestion in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) said, You need to use RegisterTouchWindow to register the created window as touch-capable and handle the meesage of [WM_TOUCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/wm-touchdown#examples) to notify the window.